# exiting a python script to terminal after the script has been restsrted

Tags: python, reboot

I've been learning python this week, which started with a snake game tutorial. I've then added features to the game to make it awesome. One feature I have added is the ability to restart the game once the snake has died. Upon death, a screen comes up which prompts the user to press y or n to restart the game. Pressing y always restarts the game, which I'm pretty pleased with. Pressing n exits the script back to the terminal, but only if the game is only played once. If the game is played twice, then n is selected, the screen goes black and everything is unresponsive. Upon snake death, a function is called. There are some other bits and pieces but I believe this is where the problem occurs:

```
while True:
    for evt in pygame.event.get():
        if evt.key == ord('y')
            restart = "y"
            break
        elif evt.key == ord('n'):
            restart = "noty"
            break
if restart == 'y'
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, × sys.argv)
else:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
    os.exit()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect those last 2 lines. Don't you only want to quit pygame?

Comment: os.execl. autocorrect!

Comment: @mauve, to be honest, I'm not really sure. My thinking was exit everything and start over

Answer (score 0):

You can just exit in the loop.

```
while True:
    for evt in pygame.event.get():
        if evt.key == ord('y')
            restart = "y"
            break
        elif evt.key == ord('n'):
            pygame.quit() # just quit here 
            sys.exit()
if restart == 'y':
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable,sys.argv)
```

There is also no `os.exit()` it is `os._exit()` which I don't think gets executed after `sys.exit()`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit):

*Note The standard way to exit is `sys.exit(n). _exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a fork().*

Comment: Thanks for replying. At the moment I'm just trying to get it to work, then I'll clean it up later. So if I add the underscore and include it before the SYS.exit it should work?

Comment: @user3692412.  I don't see why just using sys.exit will not work by itself. Your os.exit was never doing anything.

Comment: Should sys.exit necessarily exit to terminal? My thinking was after sys.exit there must be something else still running.

Comment: @user3692412. In your original code you said it worked under some circumstances, the fact that os.exit() was doing absolutely nothing should be a pointer.